# Accessing to a remote PostgreSQL server using port forwarding to another machine

Tags: networking, ssh, postgresql, port-forwarding, forwarding

I try to access to a *Server_A* on which PostgreSQL is running. This server is on a local network, that's why I have to forward port from *Server_B* which is accessible and in the same network.

To access to postgreSQl on *Server_B*, I can easily forward ports like this :

```
ssh -L 54320:Server_A:5432 user@Server_B
```

And in another terminal :

```
psql -p 54320 -d db_name -U user
```

My problem is that I want to reproduce the connection done from a machine present in the network of *Server_B*. This machine can connect itself to the database using this command :

```
psql -h Server_A -p 5432 -d db_name -U user
```

I have in fact to problems :

## I can't forward the 5432 port using the ssh command :

By inserting `5432:Server_A:5432` in the ssh command to forward the 5432 port, I have this error :

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

## I can't resolve the hostname :

Instead of directly forward the port from *server_A*, I try to forward the port from *Server_B* to have the `-h` argument in the `psql` command.

```
ssh -L 5432:127.0.0.1:5432 user@Server_B
```

And :

```
psql -h Server_A -p 5432 -d db_name -U user
```

But here, the hostname can't be resolved...

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This command:

```
ssh -L 54320:Server_A:5432 user@Server_B
```

looks good, but then when doing this:

```
psql -p 54320 -d db_name -U user
```

the ssh tunnel is not used, because by default on Unix, `psql` connects to a [Unix domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), like suggested by the error message you mention ("...accepting connections on Unix domain socket...")

You're just missing a `-h localhost` option. Try:

```
   psql -p 54320 -d db_name -U user -h localhost
```

Having previously established an ssh tunnel between `localhost:54320` and `Server_A:5432` through `Server_B`, this will reach postgres on `Server_A:5432`.

Comment: I haven't any problem with `psql -p 54320 -d db_name -U user` for the **54320** port but your solution is working for the **5432** port. Have you a solution to the second part of my question ? I try to connect psql with `-h Server_A` after forwarding my 5432 port from the intermediary server, **Server_B**. Is it something like connecting to a unix socket threw an ssh tunnel?

Comment: `psql -h Server_A` doesn't use your ssh tunnel at all so it's unclear what you're trying to achieve at that point. When doing `ssh -Lport1:host:port2`, the entry of the tunnel is at `localhost:port1`. Also, instead of saying _inserting 5432:Server_A:5432 in the ssh command_, please give the full resulting command.

Comment: super helpful, I was struggling